# very simple multidimensional array program opens Visual studio JIT?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write a complex tic tac toe game by using a multidimensional array. This is a piece of code that's supposed to print this:

```
 g | g | g
----------
 g | g | g
----------
 g | g | g
```

Where g is multidimensional array from g[1][1] to g [3][3] where g[3][3] is a string. The program bellow is supposed to print ***the first row*** from the board above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string g[3][3];
    g[1][1] = " ";
    g[2][1] = " ";
    g[3][1] = " ";
    g[1][2] = " ";
    g[2][2] = " ";
    g[3][2] = " ";
    g[1][3] = " ";
    g[2][3] = " ";
    g[3][3] = " ";
    cout << " " << g[1][1] << " " << "|" << " " << g[2][1] << " " << "|" << " " << g[3][1];
    cout << "----------------";
}
```

Upon running this program above a console opens and I get an unhandled win32 exception occured in "TESTIFICATE.exe" [2812]. I get a window where I'm supposed to select a debugger. When choosing a compiler Visual studio 2010 opens and I get some weird header files in front of me.

Note that the above program is a portion of the main program which worked swell until I added that piece of code, from which I got the unhandled win32 exception message. This has never happened to me in a program before and this isn't supposed to be happening since the program is relatively simple.

Additional details:

- OS: Windows XP professional SP3;
- I have Visual studio 2010 installed (Not the express edition)
- I'm using Codeblocks IDE;
- Upon compilation I get no warnings or errors in my IDE.

If any further details are needed post in comments and I will post them.

Comment: your indices are wrong c++ is `0` based indexed you should be using g[0][0] to g[2][2].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indexes start from `0` so `g[3][3]` is invalid memory access.

Answer (score 1):

You have off-by-one errors.

`g[1][1]` should be `g[0][0]`, `g[2][2]` should be `g[1][1]`, etc.